# How to put an image in the header in a HTML5 Boilerplate tempate

Tags: html, background-image, boilerplate

I downloaded this HTML5 Boilerplate simple responsive template: http://www.initializr.com/try : how to put an image (image.jpg) in the header with background-image? I know, it's very simple, but I'm not able. I put background-image: url("image.jpg"); within the **.header-container** class. But nothing. I tried to remove quotes: nothing. I tried to use background (not background-image): nothing

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest that you make an attempt, then lets us know what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks showdev. I put background-image: url("image.jpg"); within the .header-container class. But nothing. I tried to remove quotes: nothing. I tried to use background (not background-image): nothing.

Comment: @showdev meant to edit your original question, so that it becomes clear without reading the comments. That way it will become a future reference for people running into the same issues. That is what SO is about. Good luck!

Comment: Are you sure the path to your image is correct? You might want to check the http response of that image to see if it is 404 (not found).

Comment: for simplicity, I put the image in the same folder of the index.html